# Why a multiple inherited Exception does not catch the parent exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm assuming that following code suppose to print ("CustomExceptionALL"), but that never happens if we raise CustomException1, `CustomException2` or `CustomException3` while `CustomExceptionALL` works. Why `except CustomExceptionALL` doesn't catch `CustomException3`?

```
class CustomException1(Exception):
    pass

class CustomException2(Exception):
    pass

class CustomException3(Exception):
    pass

class CustomExceptionALL(CustomException1, CustomException2, CustomException3):
    pass

try:
    raise CustomException3
except CustomExceptionALL as e:
    print("CustomExceptionALL")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: A derived (exception) class is seen as more specific than the parent(s). So if the more general one is raised it can't be caught as more specific, only the other way around.

Comment: Multiple inheritance has nothing to do with this. This fails for the same reason `except IndexError` doesn't catch a plain `Exception`, despite `IndexError` inheriting from `Exception`.

Comment: The parent of all exceptions is `BaseException`. If an exception caught its parents then it would catch `BaseException` and thus all exceptions. Instead, an exception handler will catch the listed exceptions and all of its inherited exceptions.

Comment: If you want to catch the 3 exceptions, then `except (CustomException1, CustomException2, CustomException3) as e:` is what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you can only catch subclasses of the specified exception. In your case, these two are false:

```
isinstance(CustomException3(), CustomExceptionALL)  # False
issubclass(CustomException3, CustomExceptionALL)  # False
```

(Because you are trying to catch a `CustomExceptionALL`, but a `CustomException3` is not a `CustomExceptionALL`, but the other way around)

You can instead use a tuple of classes:

```
CustomExceptionALL = (CustomException1, CustomException2, CustomException3)

isinstance(CustomException3(), CustomExceptionALL)  # True
issubclass(CustomException3, CustomExceptionALL)  # True

try:
    raise CustomException3
except CustomExceptionALL as e:
    print("CustomExceptionALL")  # This prints
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 8):

The use case is more the other way round: you raise the derived exception and then catch it using the parent class.  For example:

```
class Brexit(Exception):
    pass

class Covid(Exception):
    pass

class DoubleWhammy(Brexit, Covid):
    pass

try:
    raise DoubleWhammy
except Brexit as e:
    print("Brexit")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```